# Ubuntu 12.10 Live USB BootError

Tags: 12.10, live-usb

I am a Linux Newbee, running ubuntu 12.04 i386 on a 64-bit machine.

Now I just downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 AMD64 iso and made a bootable USB using Startup Disk Creator. I was directed to install available updated packages, which I did install.
The Startup Disk was succesfully created.

But when I tried to boot from the USB I am getting a `BootError` message and nothing else.

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The Issue in the above scenario was with **USB Emulation in BIOS**.
After i switched the USB Emulation to 'Fixed Media', the installation was flawless.

Comment: Hey Sivan, and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please make sure to read our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#). I am only telling you this as a caution because some people add the wrong type of information in answers. Your answer is fine (and actually great for our community and is encouraged) because it *answers* your question - but keep in mind things that *don't* answer your questions belong in your question and should be edited in, or left as a comment. Just thought I'd let you know. Great answer and we hope to see you around more often! :))

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to do.
But if you would like to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 you can do this more easily, efficiently and safely by means of a system **upgrade from within your currently running Ubuntu 12.04**.
If you weren't prompted for this you may need to start "Software Sources", go to the "Updates" tab and change the option for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version:" to "For any new version".

If you would like to create a live USB disk using Ubuntu 12.10 iso file you've downloaded, I recommend installing and using the **MultiSystem** utility available from here: http://liveusb.info/